# $display not working {Verilog testbench)

Tags: verilog

I am trying to monitor the output of piece of verilog code using the $display statement . However, I am not getting any display prints. Is it because I am not using $finish ? Any help will be appreciated . I am attaching the testbench code here .

```
module t_feedback_mult;
 reg [1022:0] r;
 reg clk;
 reg reset;
 wire [9:0] lambda1;
 wire [9:0] lambda2;
 wire [9:0] lambda3;
 //wire [1022:0] error_vector;
 //wire [1022:0] corrected_codeword;
 integer count=0;


top_module TM1(r,clk,reset,lambda1,lambda2,lambda3);

 initial
 begin
    clk=1'b0;
    forever
       #5 clk=~clk;
 end

 initial
 begin
    reset=1'b0;
    #17 reset=1'b1;
 end

 initial
 begin
 //r<=(1023'd1 << 25) ^ (1023'd1<< 132) ^ (1023'd1 << 401) ^ (1023'd1 << 488) ^ (1023'd1 << 758) ^ (1023'd1 << 911) ^ (1023'd1 << 934) ^ (1023'd1 << 229) ^ (1023'd1 <<17);
    r<=1023'd7;
 end

 always@(posedge clk) begin 
    if (count == 16) 
        r<= (r<<1);
 end

 always@(posedge clk) begin 
    if (reset == 1'b1)
        count <= (count +1)%32;

    else begin
        count<= 0;
    end
  end

  always@(lambda1,lambda2,lambda3) begin 
     $display(" lambda1= %10b , lambda2= %10b , lambda3 = %10b\n",lambda1,lambda2,lambda3);

  end

 endmodule
```

Comment: the only reason for missing $display in interactive simulation could be that your signals do not toggle.  Suggestion: put $display in the 'initial' block and use '#delays' for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the lambda1, lambda2, lambda3 are not changing. But I can't check or try your code because top_module is missing.

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to print lambda* values as and when they change (which seems to be the case from what you have written), you can try using `$monitor` instead.

Try putting the following line in one of the `initial` blocks to see if it works.

`$monitor("lambda1= %10b , lambda2= %10b , lambda3 = %10b\n",lambda1,lambda2,lambda3);`

PS: Giving DUT with the TB always helps people like us to figure out and debug the issues

Comment: Or you can also try printing `$display` at every `posedge clk` but with # delays in order to print the correct values for every cycle